# Accumulating the path by recursively traversing a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have a tree structure stored in a Javascript Object and I want to extract all the possible paths from the head(`sms_in`) node to the last node in the branch. Following is a sample representation of the tree structure.

[image]

Note : Any given node can have n-number of output(`'true'` type) connections but only one input connection.  What I mean by that is, when you want to go from `sms_in` node to `isEmpty1` node, there is only one path `[{ 'sms_in' : 'true'} ]` . But if you want to go from `isEmpty1` to `dbInsert1` you have to pick '`false`' path, not the '`true`' path. Also you can go to some other nodes from `isEmpty` node as well (Not in the given case). But you can arrive to the `isEmpty` node from only one path, that is through '`sms_in`' node.

```
    var graph =
{
    "metadata": {"id": "sms_in", "type": "api", "optionsDivId": "div_sms_in", "options": {}},
    "data": {
        "true": {
            "isEmpty1": {
                "metadata": {
                    "id": "isEmpty1",
                    "type": "empty",
                    "optionsDivId": "div_isEmpty1",
                    "options": {}
                },
                "data": {
                    "true": {
                        "sms1": {
                            "metadata": {
                                "id": "sms1",
                                "type": "api",
                                "optionsDivId": "div_sms1",
                                "options": {}
                            }, "data": {"true": {}, "false": false}
                        }
                    },
                    "false": {
                        "dbInsert1": {
                            "metadata": {
                                "id": "dbInsert1",
                                "type": "dbInsert",
                                "optionsDivId": "div_dbInsert1",
                                "options": {}
                            },
                            "data": {
                                "true": {
                                    "sms2": {
                                        "metadata": {
                                            "id": "sms2",
                                            "type": "api",
                                            "optionsDivId": "div_sms2",
                                            "options": {}
                                        }, "data": {"true": {}, "false": false}
                                    }
                                }, "false": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, "false": false
    }
};
```

Here I have 2 types of nodes, where `'if/empty'` types of nodes have `'true/false'` type child nodes while all the other nodes have only `'true'` type nodes. I want to traverse the node and get the full path for all the possible cases in the following manner.

```
var output = [

 [ {'sms_in':'true'}, {'isEmpty1':'true'}, {'sms1':''}],
 [{'sms_in':'true'}, {'isEmpty1':'false'}, {'dbInsert1':'true'}, {'sms2':''}]

];
```

I can traverse the tree but I do not know how to accumulate the complete path to get the `output` in an array format. 
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  There is only one possible path from head to a given leaf node so I don't understand what "all possible paths" means or what result you're trying to accumulate.  And, what do you define as a "tail node"?

Comment: @jfriend00 I made an edit to the question, please check the question now.

Comment: First off, there's only one head node, right?  Then, I don't understand what you mean by a  "tail node".  Please describe.  Then, for a given "tail node", there's only one path to get there right?  Or do you mean something different by a "tail node"?  Still not understanding at all.  What is a path?  What is a tail node?  How can there be more than one path?

Comment: What is an "output connection"?  You're using all sorts of terminology that is not standard Javascript so please define what all these terms mean.

Comment: @jfriend00 please check now. I have explained what is output connection and input connection.

Comment: How do you go from `sms_in` to `isEmpty1`? (the question appears yesterday and i asked the same question without getting any answer.)

Comment: @NinaScholz `sms_in` will always be the head node. It is static. From there you can take the `true` path. the next node will be `isEmpty1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works, but i would not rely on it, because of the data structure.

Basically you have a structure like that

```
data.true[k].data.true  --> { k: true }
data.true[k].data.false --> { k: false }
          ^   and   ^
```

and that is very uncommon.

But the values for `sms1` and `sms2` are in my case `true` and not `''`. The wanted values are not in the given object.

```js
function traverse(o, p, last) {
    var r = [];
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        var l = typeof o[k] === 'object' && Object.keys(o[k])[0],
            temp = {};
        temp[last] = k;
        if (l && o[k][l].data && typeof o[k][l].data === 'object') {
            r = r.concat(traverse(o[k][l].data, p.concat(temp), l));
        } else {
            o[k] && r.push(p.concat(temp));
        }
    });
    return r;
}

var graph = { "metadata": { "id": "sms_in", "type": "api", "optionsDivId": "div_sms_in", "options": {} }, "data": { "true": { "isEmpty1": { "metadata": { "id": "isEmpty1", "type": "empty", "optionsDivId": "div_isEmpty1", "options": {} }, "data": { "true": { "sms1": { "metadata": { "id": "sms1", "type": "api", "optionsDivId": "div_sms1", "options": {} }, "data": { "true": {}, "false": false } } }, "false": { "dbInsert1": { "metadata": { "id": "dbInsert1", "type": "dbInsert", "optionsDivId": "div_dbInsert1", "options": {} }, "data": { "true": { "sms2": { "metadata": { "id": "sms2", "type": "api", "optionsDivId": "div_sms2", "options": {} }, "data": { "true": {}, "false": false } } }, "false": false } } } } } }, "false": false } },
    path = traverse(graph.data, [], 'sms_in');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(path, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You said the data structure is very uncommon. Can you please help me to make it better?

Comment: i do not know, for what purpose the data should be.

Comment: well, my requirement suggests me to create a decision tree like in the image, only 2 types of child has the false type of branch. That's why I came up with this structure.

Comment: IIUIC, then you need something like a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). every node has some data property, and left and right properties. this allows to iterate over left.left.left.right ... to the wanted data. you have in your case mixed up data, left and right. i suggest a structure like `{data: 'sms_in', 'true': {data: 'isEmpty', 'true': {data: 'sms1'}, 'false':{data: 'dbinsert1', 'true':{data: 'sms2'}}}}`

Comment: I checked it, the binary structure you provided, does it allow me to have more than one child for tru/false type?

Comment: basically yes, if you need something like `unknown` or so. but the result is not anymore a binary tree. but if you don't care, u can use so many branches as u need.